Oracle - Completly audit of normal users and DBA's
Which is the option to enable user audit and DBA actions?
I mean, let's say we audit a table called salary. No normal user can update the table without being audited.
But a DBA (which has full access to the database), can disable that audit and change the salary table, right? How to prevent it?

Some things you can't necessarily prevent; you have to trust someone and add as many layers of additional security in auditing in place as you can. In general, you should audit any use of "audit" commands in the first place, and audit your audit trail so you know if it has been tampered with. Often times, audit trails are written to the OS (outside the database) or copied to a SIEM tool like Splunk in real-time to prevent tampering as well. Depending on which version of Oracle you are using, your options may be more sophisticated and fine-grained, too.
